# Looking for IntelliJ Remote Dev experience similar to VS Code Remote Dev Extension Pack

Tags: intellij-idea, vscode-remote, sshfs

VS Code allows a local development experience with source code and source execution on a remote machine: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview

Is there a similar tool to this for use with IntelliJ?  The VSCode extension pack doesn't need to mount the files from the remote source locally.  It actually runs a server behind the scene on the remote box and serves over files one at a time as you need to access them to the IDE running on your local machine.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Update 2021-11-04:** JetBrains now has 2 products/features that enable this sort of remote development:

- JetBrains Projector ([ref](https://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2021/03/11/projector-is-out/))
- JetBrains Gateway ([ref](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2021/10/intellij-idea-2021-3-eap-4/#how_to_enable_remote_development_mode))

---

### Original Answer

IntelliJ IDEA doesn't have this feature at the moment, you can [follow the corresponding feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-226455) for updates.

Quoting the [blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2019/12/intellij-platform-roadmap-for-2020/):

> We’re considering the possibility to extend the “thin client” approach
> to other scenarios beyond collaborative editing, such as running the
> IDE backend in the cloud, but we aren’t ready to announce specific
> plans in that area.

Comment: This recently released jetbrains tool may be relevant: https://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2021/03/11/projector-is-out/

Comment: There is also now JetBrains Gateway that allows remote dev via SSH: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2021/10/intellij-idea-2021-3-eap-4/#how_to_enable_remote_development_mode